# How can I execute a callback on next/prev month click in YUI Calendar?

Tags: calendar, yui, yui3

I am using a YUI3 [`Calendar`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/), and I want to perform an operation when the month is changed. I would like to execute a callback when the  next/prev month buttons have been clicked in the YUI `Calendar`. How can I do that?

I tried using `A.one()`, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my current attempt:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
    <div id="event-calendar"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    YUI().use('calendar', function (Y) {

        new Y.Calendar({
            contentBox: "#event-calendar",
            width: '230px',
            showPrevMonth: false,
            showNextMonth: false,
            date: new Date()
        }).render();

        A.one(".yui3-calendarnav-nextmonth").on('click', function (ev) {
            // ... execute code here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you try this one showPrevMonth: true,showNextMonth: true ?

Comment: Is there a problem with using the `click` listener? It'll work, you just need to have one for each control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me, so I would assume that your problem is with this line:

```
A.one(".yui3-calendarnav-nextmonth").on('click', function (ev) {
```

You are selecting a single element by CSS class, but multiple elements could have the same class. So you are probably selecting another `Node` with the same class. You could probably get this code to work by being more specific with your CSS selector like so:

```
A.one("#event-calendar .yui3-calendarnav-nextmonth").on('click', function (ev) {
```

Now you are selecting an element with `class="yui3-calendarnav-nextmonth"` and a parent element with `id="event-calendar"`. That should only select the next month button for your `event-calendar`.

Here's a runnable example using alerts in the click listeners:

```js
YUI().use('calendar', function (A) {

    new A.Calendar({
        contentBox: "#event-calendar"
    }).render();

    A.one("#event-calendar .yui3-calendarnav-prevmonth").on('click', function (ev) {
        alert('prevMonth');
    });

    A.one("#event-calendar .yui3-calendarnav-nextmonth").on('click', function (ev) {
        alert('nextMonth');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/0214fdc4cccaa77d6e504320cf70a571/raw/63d260364730fb067f103c00862c7e65685256df/yui-3.18.1_build_yui_yui-min.js"></script>
<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
    <div id="event-calendar"></div>
</div>
```

See the YUI [`Calendar`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Calendar.html), [`Node`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html), and [`YUI.one()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_one) API docs for more details. Also check out MDN's [*Information: Selectors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) article to learn more about CSS selectors.